# Compare input box with system date in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I want to compare if the value in the input box is equal to the system date time. So I tried this:

```js
And("Count name is filled in the format YYMMDD hhmmss", () => {
    const dayjs = require('dayjs')
    cy.log(dayjs().format('DD/MM/YYYY'))  //Prints todays date 30/09/2021
   // cy.get('textfield').type(dayjs().format('DD/MM/YYYY')) //i

    companionPage.countNameInputBox().invoke('text').then((text) => {
        expect(text.trim()).equal(dayjs())
    })


})
```

but then I got

[image]

Any help on how I can compare the value in the input box with the date system is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues here with `expect(text.trim()).equal(dayjs())`:

1. `dayjs()` returns an object. You want a string here. You should replace it by `dayjs().format('DD/MM/YYYY')` (or similar) to get a string.
2. Your text is empty. If this is an input, you can do instead `invoke('val')` to get the value